# Avoid user impersonation for admins with DB access

Tags: authentication, passwords, admin, access-rights

If an admin has access write access to usernames and hashed passwords, he can just set them to anything he fancies and enter the system with these credentials. The system will log his access as a legitimate access by the user.

If this behaviour is unwanted, is there a best practice workaround to this?

Comment: Fire the sysadmin that exhibits such a lack of professionalism.

Comment: It's not an actual problem, it is a conceptual doubt a customer has brought up. I can't come up with a way to deny such login - perhaps only by requiring some unique physical token.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be funny, this is indeed a tough one.  Well designed two factor auth schemes can indeed help, as can separation of admin duties (db and sys) where all critical db changes (only accessible to the db admin) are logged in the system's logfiles (only modifiable by the sysadmin).  That is, as long as they don't work together...